# Why foreach instead of onSuccess for callbacks in Scala?

Tags: scala, foreach, future

Scala has foreach construct to install callback on a Future:

```
myFuture foreach{
 //computation
}
```

Initially there was onSuccess for same purpose.

onSuccess seems to be a better logical name(do this when future is complete). Why this name 'foreach' then? Does it represent something in context of callbacks which onSuccess is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between `foreach` and `onComplete` seems to be that `foreach` requires total functions as argument.

The `onComplete` was deprecated in `2.12.0`. The named reasons were:

1. There were too many callback-methods that were essentially doing the same. In order to avoid confusion, some of them were deprecated, so it is easier to decide when to use what.
2. Promote `for`-comprehensions

Link: [Deprecations: onSuccess and onFailure](https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-5).

I'm not sure what to think about this argumentation. For example, there are quite a few redundant methods on `Option`, couldn't we just remove all but one, and retain only `fold`?